# Get formatted list of values from array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

im making sort of food delivery app with some backend functional, and now im struggling with getting elements of array as formatted order strings

```
guard
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "itemlist"),
                let savedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Order].self, from: defaults)
        else {
            return
        }
        let dictionary = savedItems.compactMap({ ($0.name!, $0.price!) })
        let dishNames = dict.joined(separator: ",") //error
let order = "Заказ: \(dictionary)"
print(order)
```

result im getting:

`[("Пепперони", "45см/500р."), ("Деревенская", "45см/520р.")]`

what i want:

`Пепперони 45см/500р. Деревенская 45см/520р.`

i could do that easily in php, but im not finding analogues in swift, might anyone help me?

Comment: Instead of `($0.name!, $0.price!)` do `"\($0.name!) \($0.price!)")` in `compactMap`

Comment: Two things, you shouldn't use UserDefaults for storing this kind of data, use a file or some database solution. And also try to avoid force unwrapping and use `if let` or `guard` instead.